# How do I specify a how a python class is called by another python class?

Tags: python, class

I have two classes, for the example I will call them "Point" and "Vector" (like in math). I want one of the classes be called by the other to "convert" for example a point into the according vector ((1,2,1) -> (1,2,1)T).

```py
argsintfloat = lambda l: all(isinstance(i, (int,float,complex)) for i in l)


class Point:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if not argsintfloat(args):
            raise ValueError("non-numeral values are not supported")
        self.coordinates = args
    
    def Vector(self):
        return Vector(*self.coordinates)


class Vector:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if not argsintfloat(args):
            raise ValueError("non-numeral values are not supported")
        self.components = args

    def Point(self):
        return Point(*self.components)
```

Now when for example calling the following:

```py
point1 = Point(1,2,3,4)
vector1 = Vector(point1)
```

I just arrive at the ValueError

```py
ValueError: non-numeral values are not supported
```

as expected when the values given aren't int, float or complex. I understand why this problem is occuring; the class Vector is called instead of the function Vector in the class Point and since a class object isn't an int, float or complex... Normally I'd just call that function with

```py
point1.Point()
```

but I don't want to solve this problem with that. I want to make this as visually easy as possible without further specifying the args types conversion in **init**(). Anyone have an idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: You got a name collision (duplicate name, try rename the function: `def to_vector`

Comment: Please update your question with your real code. I get: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at `def Vector:`

Comment: There's no actual collision, but `Vector` and `Point.Vector` are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

While you could examine the arguments to `Vector.__init__` to see if you got multiple numbers or a single `Point`, it would be better to use a *class* method to decompose the `Point` into values that can be passed to `__init__`.

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if not argsintfloat(args):
            raise ValueError("non-numeral values are not supported")
        self.components = args

    def to_point(self):
        return Point(*self.components)

    @classmethod
    def from_point(cls, p: Point):
        return cls(*p.components)

point1 = Point(1,2,3,4)
vector1 = Vector.from_point(point1)
```

The same argument applies to your `Point` class:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if not argsintfloat(args):
            raise ValueError("non-numeral values are not supported")
        self.coordinates = args
    
    def to_vector(self):
        return Vector(*self.coordinates)

    @classmethod
    def from_vector(cls, v: Vector):
        return cls(*v.components)
```

In mathematical terms, `Vector` and `Point` are *isomorphic*, meaning you can losslessly convert from a value of one type to the other. Specifically, if you have a `Point` `p`, then `p == Point.from_vector(p.to_vector())`, and if you have a `Vector` `v`, then `v == Vector.from_point(v.to_point())`.

Comment: Ok so you are suggesting that what I am trying to do isn't really possible and done as you have written.

Comment: It's possible, but messy and makes `Vector.__init__` responsible for too many things. You want to try to keep methods *focused*, doing "one" thing, and letting other methods and functions be responsible for other things. Just like `from_point` knows how to get the components from a `Point`, but doesn't really know how to use them to create a `Vector`; it leaves that to `Vector.__init__`.